# Mysql Queries per Visit - Crazy High

Tags: database, mysql, performance

[image: P3 Profiler Output]

I have been wrestling with site speed for a while. I have a lot of plugins on a domain-mapped multisite network. One of the bigger offenders is Formidable Pro, which eats up a lot of resources. I compared two sites with identical plugins, however, one site has 20x the amount of content.  For reference, the other site has approximately 500 queries per visit.

Could content alone be responsible for this many queries? Database is not my strength. Any help in diagnosing and solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could start by turning on the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) and having a look at the actual queries being issued.  Keep an eye on it while enabled, don't let the log fill up your disk.

Comment: I faced a similar problem once and wrote a small plugin that analyses which functions are eating up most resources. Maybe it's  useful to you. [Code](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-plugin-profiler/). [Documentation](https://thplpr.wordpress.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I have asked my hosting company to turn on the general query log and open a few pages on the site to see if they can help diagnose the problem.  I also told them to be sure to turn it off too :-)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It goes against the grain here to recommend plugins but that's what you need here.

To view in the browser;

https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

To view in WP-CLI;

https://runcommand.io/wp/query-debug/

Both of these will list the queries and how long each one takes. That should give you enough information to make informed decisions about what to do in your case.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

In your `wp-config.php` you may need to add `defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG') or define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );` as well as `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: Thank you for this.  I will have a look at Query Monitor after my hosting company returns the results from the general query log.  WP-CLI looks interesting, but probably too complicated for me at this point.

Comment: I think you'll be pretty pleased with what Query Monitor does. Logs are hard to parse but QM will show you with element of WP triggered the query. You can always uninstall, but it's an essential development tool.